# Generally accepted algorithm for two-pass, misuse-resistant AEAD that is efficient in software

Tags: stream-cipher, authenticated-encryption, nonce

I would like to know what the standard is for two-pass, nonce-misuse-resistant AEAD that is efficient in software.  Thus, AES-SIV is excluded; modes based on a stream cipher like ChaCha20 are preferred.

Comment: AES-SIV is the standard

Answer (score 3):

AES-SIV when done well can be very fast. If you have AES-NI then it is possible to get under a cycle per byte. It is not the original AES-SIV construction but rather [this one](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/102.pdf) based on GCM (I agree that the original AES-SIV is way too slow). I suggest also that you look at the [Caesar candidates](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html). In general, there is no "standard" yet here.

Comment: If I am running on a CPU that doesn't have hardware support for AES and GHASH, this mode doesn't sound very attractive.  Can one create a similar construction based on ChaCha20 and Poly1305?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the paper, then it actually gives a generic nonce-misuse resistant construction (see Section 2). You can instantiate it with ANY PRF (which is fine for most MACs) and any secure nonce-based encryption scheme.